# Can't download semi-automatic classifications plugin

Tags: qgis-3

In QGIS 3, tried to download emi-automatic classifications plugin but get the following error message:

Couldn't load plugin 'SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method  
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 335, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "/Users/x/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/**init**.py", line 65, in classFactory
    from .semiautomaticclassificationplugin import SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 672, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/x/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/semiautomaticclassificationplugin.py", line 74, in 
    from .ui.semiautomaticclassificationplugindialog import SemiAutomaticClassificationPluginDialog
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 672, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/x/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/ui/semiautomaticclassificationplugindialog.py", line 39, in 
    from .ui_semiautomaticclassificationplugin_scatter_plot import Ui_ScatterPlot
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 672, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/x/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/ui/ui_semiautomaticclassificationplugin_scatter_plot.py", line 453, in 
    from .scatterwidget2 import ScatterWidget2
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 672, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/x/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/ui/scatterwidget2.py", line 39, in 
    import matplotlib
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 672, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
 Python version: 3.6.8 (v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 02:04:31) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]  QGIS version: 3.4.5-Madeira Madeira, exported  
Python Path:
* /Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python
* /Users/x/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
* /Users/x/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
* /Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins
* /Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/E/Python/3.6
* /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip
* /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6
* /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
* /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
* /Users/x/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
* /Users/x/Documents/mac Geology/geol Argentina/QGIS projects

Then I tried again (perhaps after re-booting my mac, don't remember) and was able to download. Closed QGIS 3, re-opened it,  checked in the "manage and install plugins" section under " installed" that it is listed and ticked, indicating that it is installed. But can't find where to access it .

What's going on ?